# Ionic4 vertical align ion-input inside ion-item

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

In ionic 4 project I need to develop a form as follows.

[image]

ion-icons of the input fields must vertically centered as the above image.
But in my implementation they are not centered as I need.

[image]

Here is my implementation

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
        <ion-list lines="none">
          <ion-item class="input-container" lines="none" align-items-center>
            <ion-icon class="custom-icon" name="mailgray" slot="start" no-padding></ion-icon>
            <ion-label position="floating" no-padding>Email</ion-label>
            <ion-input no-padding formControlName="email"></ion-input>
            <div class="email-pattern" slot="end">@company.edu</div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item class="input-container" lines="none">
            <ion-icon name="passwordgray" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
            <ion-icon name="peye" slot="end"></ion-icon>

          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        <mat-checkbox formControlName="isRememberMe">Remember me</mat-checkbox>
        <ion-button class="btn-login" expand="block" [routerLink]="['/tabs/search']">Login</ion-button>
      </form>
```

**scss**

```
.login-form {
  --background: #fafafa;
  .title {
    font-size: 25px;
    --color: #1259a1;
  }
  .sub-title {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  .btn-login {
    --background: #e88233;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  .input-container {
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    --border-radius: 5px;
    --min-height:50px; 
    --highlight-color-focused :#1259a1;
    width: 100%;
    &:first-child {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .email-pattern {
      color: #cccccc;
    }

    .custom-icon{
        width:16px;
        height: 16px;
    }
  }
}
```

As I feel the issue with `ion-item`. I tried to set height to that using `--min-height` property to `50px`. But it also did not applied.

I need to vertical align the ion-input item as the first image.